# Hierarchical cluster analysis with likert scale ordinal variables

Tags: clustering, likert, ward

I have a small dataset of 134 observations. The dataset consists of answers to a questionnaire. All the variables are measured in Likert-scale, ranging from 1 to 5 (strongly agree).

I want to perform a hierarchical cluster analysis on the variables but I am unsure about which linkage method and distance measure to use.

I have tried running Ward's linkage with squared Euclidean distance measure but I am getting conflicting answers online reading some of the posts and comments on different statistics forums. I know that Ward may not be the most appropriate linkage to use with ordinal Likert scale data like mine, but when I run the analysis with Ward's and squared Euclidean I get clusters that conceptually make a lot of sense and are well separated from each other.

So my questions:

1. Should I use this approach with my data?
2. Should I use some different measure?

Comment: Both your questions are really "should", not "can", so I've taken the liberty of editing accordingly.  Euclid, Likert and Ward are all people's names.

Comment: How many such variables?

Comment: Three variables measured using the Likert-scale

Comment: So, from one point of view there are $5^3 = 125$ distinct clusters -- from $111$ to $555$  --- that define themselves. Too many for some purposes, perhaps, but still worth looking at the pattern of frequencies.  With any luck they won't all occur in the data.

Comment: Yes. I would like to minimize the number of clusters as much as possible. Any thought on whether I should use this approach with my data or whether I should use some different measure?

Comment: Sorry, no. My experience is that clustering any kind of data is not a precise problem (because "identify the clusters that exist" is only a start) and it's certainly not got a simple obvious solution. Clustering seems to me vastly oversold, as shown for example by its use in marketing or psychology with a highly dubious assumption that people (should) subdivide easily into distinct types. To the point: Why do you want clusters? What are you going do with them? Have you tried ordination alternatives such as correspondence analysis?

Answer (score 0):

My view (and others may differ) is that when it comes to cluster analysis, if a method gives you something useful, you can use it. You say you get clusters that are well separated and that make sense.  Good.

More generally, ordinal data is tricky. Strictly speaking, the fact that a variable is ordinal means that you can't assume that the distance between (say) 1 and 2 is the same as between (say) 2 and 3. But ..... usually it's fairly close for some abstract definition of "close".  Yes, you could recode 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as 1, 2, 181,100291, 239918188 (if you are strict about what ordinal means) but, that just doesn't make any intuitive sense.

A long time ago, in grad school, I saw research trying to figure out how close some Likert scales are to being equally spaced, but I don't remember the details much less a citation.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!